# PHP rename directory failed

Tags: php, rename

Well my PHP script generated an error with a hyperlink in it.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

> `PHP Warning:  rename(./uploads/temp/00013/,./uploads/orders/39/) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: No such file or directory`

update:

actual code in PHP

> ```
>           if(!file_exists('uploads/orders/')) {
>                 mkdir('uploads/orders/'); // ensuring the orders folder exist
>             }
>             rename('uploads/temp/' . $u . '/', 'uploads/orders/' . $i . '/');
> ```

update:

Sorry, my fault. I coded to delete previous temp folder before this code execute. Thanks!

Comment: You should remove trailing slash from both arguments, i.e. `'./uploads/temp/00013'` and not `'./uploads/temp/00013/'`.

Comment: @ash108 nope, still the same. I cannot even move the directory by hard-code. I believe the problem is elsewhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one (or both) of these directories don't exist:

- uploads/temp/00013
- uploads/orders/39

Have you checked that:

- these directories exist?
- Apache/PHP has permission to read/write in these directories?
- Your current directory is really the parent directory of your "upload" directory?

Comment: the source directory exist, permission checked. it works just by yesterday, but after I edited a lot other section. It failed, and I wonder why console output have a hyperlink in it..

Answer (score 1):

When a computer tells you

> No such file or directory

the first thing you should check is if the file/directory exists. This is not a random error message, it's given only in the specific situation when a file or directory you try to use does not exist.

In this case in particular, both `./uploads/temp/00013/` and `./uploads/orders/` have to exist. If `orders` doesn't exist it's not created for you.

Comment: It works before actually, but since yesterday it failed after edited a lot of codes. I cannot even get it work by hard-code and predefined directories..